# NullPointerException with HttpsURLConnection and SSL

Tags: android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

I am receiving a NullPointerException when trying to send a POST request to a server through HTTPS. This is not a self-signed certificate (issued by CheapSSLs).

This is the error I am receiving:

```
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:378)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
06-21 18:52:37.757: E/AndroidRuntime(17985):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
```

My code is as follows:

```
URL url = new URL(mUrl);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.134", 8888));
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
builder.build(params);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + builder.mBoundary);
urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(builder.getContentLength());

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
```

The code crashes on getOutputStream.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work without a proxy?

Comment: Yes I just tried that. Silly me. Thanks haha. Spent way too much time on this without thinking of that.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to include "(Android)" in the title... tagging the question under [Android] is enough :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without including the `proxy` object in the mix... `HttpsConnection` should be enough to get the job done.